# Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: django, gravatar

I want to use gravatar on django:

```
import hashlib
import urllib
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


# return only the URL of the gravatar
# TEMPLATE USE:  {{ email|gravatar_url:150 }}
@register.filter
def gravatar_url(email, size=40):
    default = "https://example.com/static/images/defaultavatar.jpg"
    return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?%s" % (
    hashlib.md5(email.lower()).hexdigest(), urllib.urlencode({'d': default, 's': str(size)}))


# return an image tag with the gravatar
# TEMPLATE USE:  {{ email|gravatar:150 }}
@register.filter
def gravatar(email, size=40):
    url = gravatar_url(email, size)
    return mark_safe('<img src="%s" height="%d" width="%d">' % (url, size, size))
```

I am using this link:
[Django gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/django/)

I put this code in a file called 'grav_tag'
and load with:

```
{% load  grav_tag %}
```

im my template:

```
{{ user.email|gravatar:150 }}
```

but I get this error

```
Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user.email` is a Unicode string, whereas the hash function can only operate on bytes. So you need to convert (i.e. [encode](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes)) the string into a series of bytes, based on some Unicode character encoding.

Historically, email addresses were restricted to ASCII, but [nowadays they can be UTF-8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531) as well. The [gravatar documentation](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/) doesn't mention an encoding, so it's not clear if they support UTF-8 email addresses.

The simple answer is just to use `email.lower().encode("utf-8")`. Since ASCII is the same as UTF-8 throughout the ASCII range, this should work for all email addresses that Gravatar supports.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Python 3 right now? It because you need to encode your email as `utf-8`, example `email.encode('utf-8')`. here'is what I using for my currently project...

```
import hashlib
from django import template

try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urllib import urlencode

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def gravatar(email, size="75"):
    """
    <img src='{{ request.user.email|gravatar:"75" }}'>
    """
    gravatar_url = "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + \
        hashlib.md5(email.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() + "?"
    gravatar_url += urlencode({'d': 'retro', 's': str(size)})
    return gravatar_url
```

hope it usefull..